# C#, System.Timers.Timer, run every min in sync with system clock

Tags: c#, timer, system, synchronization, clock

I am trying to get a timer run every minute in sync with the system clock (00:01:00, 00:02:00, 00:03:00, etc).  Will the following code produce a stable timer? I've tried running it. The timer does precisely run every min. But the question is will it start to wander off, say, after several months?

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer;

public frmMain()
{
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.AutoReset = false;
            timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Interval = GetInterval();
            timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
            //Do processing

            timer.Interval = GetInterval();
            timer.Start();

}
private double GetInterval()
{
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            return ((60 - now.Second) * 1000 - now.Millisecond);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#, System.Timers.Timer, run every 15min in sync with system clock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896536/c-system-timers-timer-run-every-15min-in-sync-with-system-clock) by the same user.

Answer (score 4):

It won't.

`DateTime.Now` uses the system clock as the reference timer, so your timer will *always* stay in sync with it, modulus the few milliseconds of system clock resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how it can wander off, everytime the timer ticks, it determines how long it is to the next exact minute and sets the interval accordingly.  In theory it is actually quite ingenious, because I timer by itself would wander off.  The only way to know for sure would be to test it of course, so as long as your UI doesn't freeze for more then 60 seconds, (maybe 50s to play it safe) there won't be a problem.  Keep in mind that laptops will often go to sleep when left for a time, or the lid is closed, this will cause a glitch.

Depending on what you are attemping to do though, why not just use the system time, to send an event everytime the minute changes?

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't drift, but there will (inevitably) be jitter as Timer callbacks are rarely bang on the requested interval.

The only *potential* problem I can see with this code is if the `ThreadPool` were under such strain that your timer callback was not dequeued and executed within a minute interval, resulting in a skipped minute.

This seems somewhat unlikely, but not completely beyond the realms of possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The big picture looks fine, `GetInterval` will always return a positive value, and so on. I only see a few caveats:

1. If standby/resume happens then you may have one run at a non-round time
2. If timer_Elapsed takes more than a minute to complete then you will miss a beat
3. If the system is so overloaded that timer_Elapsed is scheduled 40/50 seconds in delay AND timer_Elapsed takes more than `60 - delay` seconds, you will miss a beat

Comment: It depends on how vital is for you never to miss a minute, how much do you expect your scheduled operations to run (worst time), and what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: as Bill said, the solution depends on the problem.  If you need something to run 1440 times a day (thats once a minute) then maybe you should keep track of how many times it has run against how many times it should have run.  if it is a timer that needs to run everyminute, then everybeat check if it ran in the last minute, if not run twice this time etc....

Comment: if it's polling for updates then you can ignore the skipped beats altoghether, etc... [btw, my real name is not Bill xD]